# simplexml error handling php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using the following code:

```
function GetTwitterAvatar($username){
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://twitter.com/users/".$username.".xml");
$imgurl = $xml->profile_image_url;
return $imgurl;
}

function GetTwitterAPILimit($username, $password){
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://$username:$password@twitter.com/account/rate_limit_status.xml");
$left = $xml->{"remaining-hits"};
$total = $xml->{"hourly-limit"};
return $left."/".$total;
}
```

and getting these errors when the stream cannot connect:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://twitter.com/users/****.xml) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://twitter.com/users/****.xml" 

Warning: simplexml_load_file(http://...@twitter.com/account/rate_limit_status.xml) [function.simplexml-load-file]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable

Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "http://***:***@twitter.com/account/rate_limit_status.xml"
```

How can I handle these errors so I can display a user friendly message instead of what is shown above?

Comment: Consider changing the selected answer? The question asks "How can I handle these errors?" the selected answer merely tells you how to avoid having to.

Comment: @TimOgilvy done, thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've found a nice example in the [php documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php).

**So the code is:**

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxe = simplexml_load_string("<?xml version='1.0'><broken><xml></broken>");
if (false === $sxe) {
    echo "Failed loading XML\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
}
```

**And the output, as we/I expected:**

> Failed loading XML
>
> ```
> Blank needed here
> parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected
> Opening and ending tag mismatch: xml line 1 and broken
> Premature end of data in tag broken line 1
> ```

Comment: However, this CANNOT get all warning messages dumped by simplexml_load_string.

Answer (score 49):

I thinks this is a better way

```
$use_errors = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
if (false === $xml) {
  // throw new Exception("Cannot load xml source.\n");
}
libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($use_errors);
```

more info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php

Comment: Only one that answers the question. Use it with `libxml_get_errors()` or `libxml_get_last_error()` to get the error message(s).

Comment: However, this CANNOT get all warning messages dumped by simplexml_load_file.

Comment: I tried this but got a warning message, so I simply did $xml = @simplexml_load_file($url); and no warnings and handles error as expected

Answer (score 10):

If you look at the manual, there is an options parameter:

```
SimpleXMLElement simplexml_load_file ( string $filename [, string $class_name = "SimpleXMLElement" [, int $options = 0 [, string $ns = "" [, bool $is_prefix = false ]]]] )
```

Options list is available: http://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php

This is the correct way to suppress warnings parsing warnings:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('file.xml', 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOWARNING);
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, still generated an E_WARNING in PHP 5.4.x

Comment: This answer is a simple solution that works, saved me headache! Note to those that may have errors: if you have more than one LIBXML_XXXX, be sure to seperate by pipe like LIBXML_NOCDATA | LIBXML_COMPACT | LIBXML_NOWARNING

Answer (score 7):

This is an old question, but is still relevant today.

The correct way to handle exceptions when using the oop SimpleXMLElment is like so.

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE); // this turns off spitting errors on your screen
try {
  $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStringOfData);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Do something with the exception, or ignore it.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

My little code:

```
try {
    libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString);
    echo '<pre>'.htmlspecialchars($xml->asXML()).'</pre>';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ' . $e->getMessage() . chr(10);
    echo 'Failed loading XML: ' . chr(10);
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo '- ' . $error->message;
    }
}
```

Result example:

```
Caught exception: String could not be parsed as XML
Failed loading XML: 
- Opening and ending tag mismatch: Body line 3 and Bod-y
```

Answer (score -1):

The documentation says that in the case of an error, simplexml_load_file returns FALSE. So, you can use the "shut-up" operator (@) in combination with a conditional statement:

```
if (@simplexml_load_file($file))
{
    // continue
}
else 
{
    echo 'Error!';
}
```

Comment: Not the shut-up not the shut up, please !

Comment: so something like this?  

function GetTwitterAvatar($username){
if(@simplexml_load_file("http://twitter.com/users/".$username.".xml")){
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://twitter.com/users/".$username.".xml");
$imgurl = $xml->profile_image_url;
return $imgurl;
} else {
return 'error';
}
}

Comment: You can do it without calling simplexml_load_file twice: $xml = @simplexml_load_file("..."); if ($xml) { ... } else { return 'Error'; }

Comment: mere-teresa, but he needs to suppress the warning here... Of course, you can also use the display_errors setting or convert errors to exceptions and then use try/catch, but this is much simpler...

Comment: @IgnasR you can do it even simpler: if (!$xml = simplexml_load_file($file)) { echo 'Error!'; return false; } else { //your code }

Comment: Added comment to original question to recommend changing the selected answer, as this is a non-answer, and equates to "how to not-have-to handle errors on simplexml". The question was how to handle them - not how to avoid having to handle them.