# simplexml_load_file() error happening in only localhost/xampp

Tags: simplexml, php

I've been getting an error in a PHP script:

> simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity

the problem is I get this error only when I run the script in `localhost (XAMPP)`, when I run it in my site everything becomes fine.

So I can't test the code in localhost.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307275/simplexml-error-handling-php

Comment: No, that doesn't solve, but yes thanks for the link. might be useful in future. I think the problem is in 'port' since it working fine in hosting server :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this when I tried and open XML files on a HTTPS website before, turned out I was lacking SSL.

Are you using the SSL enabled XAMPP release?

Comment: No.. But I tested in my hosting server, And it's working fine there and I don't have SSL in that server, but Still working :S

Comment: No, but the webserver still needs SSL enabled to connect to HTTPS resources. Even if you're not using HTTPS on your site. That's the point I was getting at.