# PHP Curl detect bad xml

Tags: php, xml, curl

I have been experiencing some bad returns on xml that I get from another server. I'd like to add some reporting on this for myself but I need to find a sure fire way to identify when simple xml fails.

The errors happen on this specific point `$xmlResponse = new SimpleXMLElement( $response );`

so basically if there is `SimpleXMLElement->__construct` error trigger i want to detect this and fire my reporting.

E.g.

```
if($xmlResponse === Fail){
 // Do reporting
}
```

any ideas appreciated. I also cant rely on http responses as the response code could be fine but there might be issues with the xml itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simplexml error handling php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1307275/simplexml-error-handling-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to check if the xml is malformed,

```
if(!(@DOMDocument::loadXML($xml))){
  // do reporting
}
```

- funfact: pretty much the only difference between DOMDocument's loadXML and loadHTML is that loadHTML accepts malformed xml, while loadXML does not.

Comment: Will this work even if its a background process run by ajax though?

Comment: @DCdaz PHP doesn't care if its invoked by cli, page load, ajax call, or anything else. yes, it will work